# 5G interference with weather observation, a thing already?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, weather-satellites

The scientific community expressed concern that global 5G would potentially threaten weather forecasts by scrambling frequencies in the microwave spectrum used for water vapor, atmospheric temperature and snow/ice observation by weather satellites.

https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01305-4

The first 5G installations are out now, mostly in Asia i think. Politics aside, please, is there any effect on weather forecast known already, or is it too early to state ?

[WMO press release](https://public.wmo.int/en/media/news/wmo-expresses-concern-about-radio-frequency-decision) from November. They say that if 5G is rolled out too fast, the limits set from the regulators will be too low maintain forecast quality and range.

Comment: 5G uses frequenzies from 3,5GHZ to 100GHZ.The infra red frequenzy band is from 300GHZ to 430THZ.So it is highly unlikely with any interference from the 5G frequenzy bands.

Comment: Corrected :-) But you say it's a false alarm ?

Comment: i think it is false alarm,but it is microwave radiation so it might interfere with radar and possibly some weapon systems but not with remote temparature sensing.i know too little about this to make an answer.

Comment: your edits sendt this question stright into the frequenzy range weather satelites use to detect moisture content in the atmosphere,it might be useful to ask over at space exploration about what frequenzies the weather satelites use for the detection of moisture.

Comment: A picture is in the nature link ...

Comment: Well, the more 5G sources there will be, the more signal pollution. At radio frequencies astronomers have to deal with signal pollution due to civilization on a regular basis, and techniques exist to filter those out. However I don't know whether the same tricks work for IR and radio.